# Extract dates from column names to create time series

Tags: r, indexing, time-series, tidyr

I have a data frame with evaluation sites, the calculation of different vegetation indices and different dates. I need join all information in a new data.frame where the date information that is embedded in the vegetation indices is contained in a separate column in the output data frame.

My data frame has the following structure:

```
df.16 <- data.frame(ID=c("a","b","c"),
                    SUGAR=c(152232.92, 117937.06, 72080.81), 
                    EVI_20160616_re=c(0.51, 0.59, 0.37), # The date is included in the column name.
                    EVI_20161006_re=c(0.59, 0.34, 0.46),
                    GNDVI_20160616_re=c(0.51, 0.59, 0.37),
                    GNDVI_20161006_re=c(0.59, 0.34, 0.46),
                    NDVI_20160616_re=c(0.51, 0.59, 0.37),
                    NDVI_20161006_re=c(0.59, 0.34, 0.46),
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I would like to get a new data.frame with the following structure, such that each observation (row) lists the vegetation indices (EVI, GNDVI, and NDVI) and the SUGAR column for a given date and evaluation site.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When you join dataframes, you need (at least) two dataframes. Your code only shows one dataframe. Where is the other dataframe?

Comment: I Sorry the title of question was incorrect

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Bryan. It appears that the intent of your question is to extract the dates from the column names for the vegetation indices, so I edited your question accordingly. Please review & confirm that I understand your question accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df.16 %>% 
  gather(key = measurement_date, value = value, -ID, -SUGAR) %>% 
  mutate(measurement = gsub("[^A-Z.]", "",  measurement_date), 
         DATE = gsub("[^0-9.]", "",  measurement_date) %>%
             as.Date(format = "%Y%m%d")) %>%
  select(-measurement_date) %>%
  spread(key = measurement, value = value)

#   ID     SUGAR       DATE  EVI GNDVI NDVI
# 1  a 152232.92 2016-06-16 0.51  0.51 0.51
# 2  a 152232.92 2016-10-06 0.59  0.59 0.59
# 3  b 117937.06 2016-06-16 0.59  0.59 0.59
# 4  b 117937.06 2016-10-06 0.34  0.34 0.34
# 5  c  72080.81 2016-06-16 0.37  0.37 0.37
# 6  c  72080.81 2016-10-06 0.46  0.46 0.46
```

Answer (score 1):

Using R 4.0 and the latest versions of tidyr (1.1.0) and dplyr (1.0.0), `pivot_longer()` supports splitting column names into multiple variables in the narrow format data set. Once split, we can then use `pivot_wider()` to create columns for `EVI`, `GNDVI` and `NDVI`. Since the `_re` part of the variable names in the input data frame appear to be irrelevant, we use `select()` to remove them from the output.

```
df.16 <- data.frame(ID=c("a","b","c"),
                    SUGAR=c(152232.92, 117937.06, 72080.81), 
                    EVI_20160616_re=c(0.51, 0.59, 0.37), # The date is included in the column name.
                    EVI_20161006_re=c(0.59, 0.34, 0.46),
                    GNDVI_20160616_re=c(0.51, 0.59, 0.37),
                    GNDVI_20161006_re=c(0.59, 0.34, 0.46),
                    NDVI_20160616_re=c(0.51, 0.59, 0.37),
                    NDVI_20161006_re=c(0.59, 0.34, 0.46),
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df.16 %>% 
     pivot_longer(.,-c(ID,SUGAR),names_to=c("variable","DATE","RE"),
                  names_sep = "_",values_to = "value") %>%
     select(-RE) %>% 
     pivot_wider(.,c(ID,DATE,SUGAR),names_from=variable,values_from=value)
```

...and the output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  ID    DATE       SUGAR   EVI GNDVI  NDVI
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a     20160616 152233.  0.51  0.51  0.51
2 a     20161006 152233.  0.59  0.59  0.59
3 b     20160616 117937.  0.59  0.59  0.59
4 b     20161006 117937.  0.34  0.34  0.34
5 c     20160616  72081.  0.37  0.37  0.37
6 c     20161006  72081.  0.46  0.46  0.46
```

**NOTE:** although the data to the right of the decimal point for `SUGAR` isn't printed in the output, by casting the result with `as.data.frame()` one can see that the data is accurate.

If we need to convert the date value to a Date object in R, we can add `mutate()` to make the conversion:

```
df.16 %>% group_by(ID,SUGAR) %>% 
     pivot_longer(.,-c(ID,SUGAR),names_to=c("variable","DATE","RE"),
                  names_sep = "_",values_to = "value") %>%
     select(-RE) %>% 
     pivot_wider(.,c(ID,DATE,SUGAR),names_from=variable,values_from=value) %>%
     mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE,"%Y%m%d"))
```

...and the output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   ID, SUGAR [3]
  ID    DATE         SUGAR   EVI GNDVI  NDVI
  <chr> <date>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a     2016-06-16 152233.  0.51  0.51  0.51
2 a     2016-10-06 152233.  0.59  0.59  0.59
3 b     2016-06-16 117937.  0.59  0.59  0.59
4 b     2016-10-06 117937.  0.34  0.34  0.34
5 c     2016-06-16  72081.  0.37  0.37  0.37
6 c     2016-10-06  72081.  0.46  0.46  0.46
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @LenGreski answer with `pivot_longer/pivot_wider`, it could be also done with `pivot_longer` alone by making use of the `names_pattern` to capture groups of characters as regex pattern (`(...)`) based on the patterns in column name.  Here, the regex used is to capture the first set of characters that are not a `_` (`([^_]+)`) from the start (`^`) of the string, followed by a `_`, then second set of characters not an underscore, followed by the `_re` and if needed, convert the 'DATE' to `Date` class (`ymd` from `lubridate`).  Also, note the sequence specifying the vector in `names_to`.  Here, the value part specifies the columns to which value should go into and the 'DATE' the second part of the column name

```
library(dplyr) # 1.0.0
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
df.16 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("_"), names_to = c(".value", "DATE"), 
         names_pattern= "^([^_]+)_([^_]+)_re") %>%
  mutate(DATE = ymd(DATE))
# A tibble: 6 x 6
#  ID      SUGAR DATE         EVI GNDVI  NDVI
#  <chr>   <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a     152233. 2016-06-16  0.51  0.51  0.51
#2 a     152233. 2016-10-06  0.59  0.59  0.59
#3 b     117937. 2016-06-16  0.59  0.59  0.59
#4 b     117937. 2016-10-06  0.34  0.34  0.34
#5 c      72081. 2016-06-16  0.37  0.37  0.37
#6 c      72081. 2016-10-06  0.46  0.46  0.46
```